# Capture Key Press event using Content scripting in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to do the following while building chrome extension

My manifest file

```
  "commands": {
      "detect" : {
          "_execute_browser_action": {
              "suggested_key": {
                "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+1",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+1",
                "chromeos": "Ctrl+Shift+1",
                "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
              }
            },
            "_execute_page_action": {
              "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1",
                "windows": "Alt+Shift+1",
                "mac": "Command+Shift+1"
              }
          },
          "description": "Key press Event",
          "global": true
      }
     },
     "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "js": ["main.js"]
      }
```

My main.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command === "detect") {
        alert("detect");
        console.log('Command:', command);
    }
});
```

So, I am planning to capture key press event after injecting my js using content scripting. However, I am unable to capture any keypress event.

Comment: 1. The "commands" declaration is invalid, see the documentation 2. Content scripts can access only 4 chrome API, see the documentation. You need an event page script, see the documentation.

Comment: What you have so far (even though what you have shown is not complete) is way off from what you would need to accomplish what you desire (even though what you desire is not clear). Thus, getting this to work is basically writing the functionality from scratch, which is too broad. Thus, I'm not sure if I should vote to close this as a debugging question which does not have a MCVE, as just too broad, or unclear.

Comment: I suggest you read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) (perhaps along with the pages linked from the overview). The [architecture section](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done. You will probably also want to read [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: What kind of key press events are you wanting to "capture"? Are you wanting to capture all `keypress` events on all/some content pages? Are you just wanting to execute some function on a *specific* key press? Please provide more detail.